# Supporting ISupportInitialize using json.net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft json.net serializer to serialize some of my models to json.
Some of them are complex containing circular references. Since circular references are not serializable these are dealt with setting `ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`.
The references are restored after other serializations using ISupportInitialize.
ISupportInitialize is also used to initialize heavy properties (images) from database. Some classes do not have a default ctor (needs [NotNull] argument), I understand my heavy properties can be lazy, but since my ISupportInitialize works fine (and is tested) with previous serializers I would prefere to use that mechanism.

I'm trying to get the json.net serializer to detect types implementing the ISupportInitialize interface and call the appropriate interface methods. This is simple when the actual serialized/deserialized object implements the interface but tougher (or at least not intuitive for me) when some property deep in the object graph implements it. I've tried writing a custom  converter but without luck. Below is a simple example of what I would like to accomplish

```
 public class SupportsInitialize : ISupportInitialize
    {
        public void BeginInit(){throw new NotImplementedException();}

        public void EndInit(){throw new NotImplementedException();}
    }

    [Test]
    public void MakeSerializerCallBeginAndEndInit()
    {
        var supportsInitialize = new ToBeSerialized() {SupportsInitialize = new SupportsInitialize()};
        // before serializing any property implementing ISupportInitialize (ToBeSerialized.SupportsInitialize in this case) its BeginInit should be called
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(supportsInitialize);
        // after deserializing any property implementing ISupportInitialize its EndInit should be called
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToBeSerialized>(json); 
    }

    public class ToBeSerialized
    {
        public SupportsInitialize SupportsInitialize { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanx for any help pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to manually add [`[OnDeserializing]` and `[OnDeserialized]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) callbacks that call `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()` to each of your [`ISupportInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) types, you could create a custom subclass of [`DefaultContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) that calls the appropriate methods automatically:

```
public class ISupportInitializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    // As of 7.0.1, Json.NET suggests using a static instance for "stateless" contract resolvers, for performance reasons.
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver__ctor_1.htm
    // "Use the parameterless constructor and cache instances of the contract resolver within your application for optimal performance."
    static ISupportInitializeContractResolver instance;

    // Using a static constructor enables fairly lazy initialization.  http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx
    static ISupportInitializeContractResolver() { instance = new ISupportInitializeContractResolver(); }

    public static ISupportInitializeContractResolver Instance { get { return instance; } }

    readonly SerializationCallback onDeserializing;
    readonly SerializationCallback onDeserialized;

    protected ISupportInitializeContractResolver()
        : base()
    {
        onDeserializing = (o, context) =>
            {
                var init = o as ISupportInitialize;
                if (init != null)
                    init.BeginInit();
            };
        onDeserialized = (o, context) =>
            {
                var init = o as ISupportInitialize;
                if (init != null)
                    init.EndInit();
            };
    }

    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
        if (typeof(ISupportInitialize).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
        {
            contract.OnDeserializingCallbacks.Add(onDeserializing);
            contract.OnDeserializedCallbacks.Add(onDeserialized);
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = ISupportInitializeContractResolver.Instance };
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToBeSerialized>(jsonString, settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't need that. You could try to serialize using appropriate settings:

```
// intended is not needed, but it makes it easier to know whats going on.
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
    });
```

and deserialize as usual:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToBeSerialized>(json);
```

---

To call your Initializ methods, you could try to use JSON.NET's [SerializationCallbacks](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm):

```
public class ToBeSerialized
{
    // [...]

    // this is probably superflous if the callbacks do what you want, you can move the code there
    public SupportsInitialize SupportsInitialize { get; set; }

    [OnDeserializing]
    internal void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.SupportsInitialize.BeginInit();
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.SupportsInitialize.EndInit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nozzleman. There are more to the implementations in my ISupportInitialize than just restoring the circular references (unfortunately). I also tried your snippet with a Parent Child relationship. Where they references each other and it will not restore the circular reference completely. The childs parent will be null.

Comment: In Order for JSON.NET to work, there needs to be a default (parameterless) ctor (which can be private). Try that to make the deep loop work. As for the "other things", pls update your questin to clearify what you are trying to do and where you fail

Comment: yeah, thats what i thought, as for the other stuff, im not really sure what you are trying to achieve, so meybe its a good idea to update and clearify your question, maaybe providing a min example which reproduces the issue.

Comment: I'll check it out on my models and let you know how it works out for the circular references.

Comment: Regarding the callbacks. I've seen them but since I'm wrapping the serializer anyway I might as well check for ISupportInitialize there and call the corresponding methods. What I was hoping for was a way to register a callback or subclassing serializer so that I could do the check there, hence be more open if someone added a property deep in the model that was ISupportInitialize.

Comment: Well, just think about wether or not this answer solves your problem and [consider accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or feel free to ask another question or clearify the current one. Take note taht this diskussion is getting a bit blewed up over time ;)